# Can not connect toTor : not able to authenticate relays

Tags: configuration, directory, client

I set up a DirServer and 3 relays, but my client can not build a circuit.
My info.log is like this:

```
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [notice] Tor 0.3.2.10 (git-0edaa32732ec8930) opening new log file.
Apr 23 19:52:26.597 [notice] Tor 0.3.2.10 (git-0edaa32732ec8930) running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.0g, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.2, and Libzstd 1.3.3.
Apr 23 19:52:26.598 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 23 19:52:26.598 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Apr 23 19:52:26.598 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Apr 23 19:52:26.603 [warn] You have used DirAuthority or AlternateDirAuthority to specify alternate directory authorities in your configuration. This is potentially dangerous: it can make you look different from all other Tor users, and hurt your anonymity. Even if you've specified the same authorities as Tor uses by default, the defaults could change in the future. Be sure you know what you're doing.
Apr 23 19:52:26.603 [warn] TestingTorNetwork is set. This will make your node almost unusable in the public Tor network, and is therefore only advised if you are building a testing Tor network!
Apr 23 19:52:26.603 [notice] Scheduler type KIST has been enabled.
Apr 23 19:52:26.603 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 23 19:52:26.604 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [warn] Your log may contain sensitive information - you disabled SafeLogging, and you're logging more than "notice". Don't log unless it serves an important reason. Overwrite the log afterwards.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] options_act_reversible(): Recomputed OOS thresholds: ConnLimit 60, ConnLimit_ 65504, ConnLimit_high_thresh 65440, ConnLimit_low_thresh 49128
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [notice] Not disabling debugger attaching for unprivileged users.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] tor_lockfile_lock(): Locking "/var/lib/tor/lock"
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] or_state_load(): Loaded state from "/var/lib/tor/state"
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] sampled_guards_update_from_consensus(): Not updating the sample guard set; we have no live consensus.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards(): Trying to sample a reachable guard: We know of 0 in the USABLE_FILTERED set.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (That isn't enough. Trying to expand the sample.)
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] entry_guards_expand_sample(): Not expanding the sample guard set; we have no live consensus.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (After filters [b], we have 0 guards to consider.)
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] circuit_build_times_parse_state(): Adding 0 timeouts.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] circuit_build_times_parse_state(): Loaded 6/6 values from 4 lines in circuit time histogram
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] circuit_build_times_filter_timeouts(): We had 0 timeouts out of 6 build times, and filtered 0 above the max of 60000
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] read_file_to_str(): Could not open "/var/lib/tor/router-stability": No such file or directory
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] init_cookie_authentication(): Generated auth cookie file in '"/var/run/tor/control.authcookie"'.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] scheduler_kist_set_full_mode(): Setting KIST scheduler with kernel support (KIST mode)
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] cell_ewma_set_scale_factor(): Disabled cell_ewma algorithm because of value in Default value
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] add_predicted_port(): New port prediction added. Will continue predictive circ building for 2359 more seconds.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] crypto_global_init(): NOT using OpenSSL engine support.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] evaluate_evp_for_aes(): This version of OpenSSL has a known-good EVP counter-mode implementation. Using it.
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] trusted_dirs_load_certs_from_string(): Adding cached certificate for directory authority DA with signing key A1A869698E89F45DE3441C81F0AC1E4D1C31118C
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] read_file_to_str(): Could not open "/var/lib/tor/cached-consensus": No such file or directory
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] read_file_to_str(): Could not open "/var/lib/tor/unverified-consensus": No such file or directory
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] A consensus needs 1 good signatures from recognized authorities for us to accept it. This one has 1 (DA).
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] scheduler_kist_set_full_mode(): Setting KIST scheduler with kernel support (KIST mode)
Apr 23 19:52:26.000 [info] Choosing expected valid-after time as 2019-04-24 02:52:40: consensus_set=1, interval=20
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] microdesc_cache_reload(): Reloaded microdescriptor cache. Found 6612 descriptors.
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] update_consensus_networkstatus_fetch_time_impl(): Live microdesc consensus was the most recent until 2019-04-23 19:52:20 and will expire at 2019-04-23 19:52:40; fetching the next one at 2019-04-23 19:52:36.
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] cell_ewma_set_scale_factor(): Disabled cell_ewma algorithm because of value in Default value
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] read_file_to_str(): Could not open "/var/lib/tor/unverified-microdesc-consensus": No such file or directory
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] tor_mmap_file(): Could not open "/var/lib/tor/cached-descriptors" for mmap(): No such file or directory
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] routerlist_remove_old_routers(): We have 0 live routers and 0 old router descriptors.
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] tor_mmap_file(): Could not open "/var/lib/tor/cached-extrainfo" for mmap(): No such file or directory
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] sampled_guards_update_from_consensus(): Updating sampled guard status based on received consensus.
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards(): Trying to sample a reachable guard: We know of 0 in the USABLE_FILTERED set.
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (That isn't enough. Trying to expand the sample.)
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] entry_guards_expand_sample(): Expanding the sample guard set. We have 21 guards in the sample, and 1 eligible guards to extend it with.
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] entry_guards_expand_sample(): Not expanding the guard sample any further; just hit the maximum sample threshold of 20
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (After filters [b], we have 0 guards to consider.)
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [notice] Signaled readiness to systemd
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] routerlist_remove_old_routers(): We have 0 live routers and 0 old router descriptors.
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] tor_getpwnam(): Caching new entry debian-tor for debian-tor
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [notice] Opening Control listener on /var/run/tor/control
Apr 23 19:52:27.000 [info] tor_getpwnam(): Caching new entry debian-tor for debian-tor
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] circuit_predict_and_launch_new(): Have 0 clean circs (0 internal), need another exit circ.
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] choose_good_exit_server_general(): Found 2 servers that might support 0/0 pending connections.
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] choose_good_exit_server_general(): Chose exit server '$1DDF03E9C34867C581F0DE8D6EAEC30A9188DB11~relay2 at 149.129.x.x'
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] extend_info_from_node(): Not including the ed25519 ID for $1DDF03E9C34867C581F0DE8D6EAEC30A9188DB11~relay2 at 149.129.x.x, since it won't be able to authenticate it.
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards(): Trying to sample a reachable guard: We know of 0 in the USABLE_FILTERED set.
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (That isn't enough. Trying to expand the sample.)
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] entry_guards_expand_sample(): Expanding the sample guard set. We have 21 guards in the sample, and 1 eligible guards to extend it with.
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] entry_guards_expand_sample(): Not expanding the guard sample any further; just hit the maximum sample threshold of 20
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (After filters [17], we have 0 guards to consider.)
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] select_entry_guard_for_circuit(): Absolutely no sampled guards were available. Marking all guards for retry and starting from top again.
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [warn] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] onion_populate_cpath(): Generating cpath hop failed.
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] circuit_mark_for_close_(): Circuit 0 (id: 1) marked for close at ../src/or/circuitbuild.c:514 (orig reason: -2, new reason: 0)
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] circuit_free(): Circuit 0 (id: 1) has been freed.
Apr 23 19:52:28.000 [info] or_state_save(): Saved state to "/var/lib/tor/state"
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] circuit_predict_and_launch_new(): Have 0 clean circs (0 internal), need another exit circ.
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] choose_good_exit_server_general(): Found 2 servers that might support 0/0 pending connections.
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] **choose_good_exit_server_general(): Chose exit server '$1DDF03E9C34867C581F0DE8D6EAEC30A9188DB11~relay2 at 149.129.x.x'
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] extend_info_from_node(): Not including the ed25519 ID for $1DDF03E9C34867C581F0DE8D6EAEC30A9188DB11~relay2 at 149.129.x.x, since it won't be able to authenticate it.**
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards(): Trying to sample a reachable guard: We know of 0 in the USABLE_FILTERED set.
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (That isn't enough. Trying to expand the sample.)
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] entry_guards_expand_sample(): Expanding the sample guard set. We have 21 guards in the sample, and 1 eligible guards to extend it with.
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] entry_guards_expand_sample(): Not expanding the guard sample any further; just hit the maximum sample threshold of 20
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] sample_reachable_filtered_entry_guards():   (After filters [17], we have 0 guards to consider.)
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] select_entry_guard_for_circuit(): Absolutely no sampled guards were available. Marking all guards for retry and starting from top again.
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [warn] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] onion_populate_cpath(): Generating cpath hop failed.
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] circuit_mark_for_close_(): Circuit 0 (id: 2) marked for close at ../src/or/circuitbuild.c:514 (orig reason: -2, new reason: 0)
Apr 23 19:52:29.000 [info] circuit_free(): Circuit 0 (id: 2) has been freed.
```

Why it not able to authenticate the relay?
My relays already finished handshakes with each other, so I can't figure out why.

And my DirServer logs a lot like:

```
Apr 24 10:49:31.000 [notice] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 14)
```

Is this normal?

Comment: I think you need at least 2 directory authorities running. You should take a look at Chutney to see how it starts up a small Tor network.

Comment: Thank you very much Steve, I already solved this problem. It is caused by my firewall figuration.